# extending base class by casting it to derived and setting the data

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Assume I have this:

```
class Base {
public:
    int a;
    Base() : a(5) {}
};

template<class T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    T value;
};
```

The code below works but I want to know what can be the challenges of using such approach:

```
Base * base = new Base;
Derived<int> * derived = static_cast<Derived<int>*>(base);
derived->value = 5;
Derived<String> * derived1 = static_cast<Derived<String>*>(base);
derived1->value = "test";

Derived<String> * newderived = static_cast<Derived<String>*>(base);
std::cout << newderived->value;
Derived<int> * newderived1 = static_cast<Derived<int>*>(base);
std::cout << newderived1->value;
//Output: test1
```

Or how can I achieve such thing in a different, safer way. I want to pass a class through 5 functions that will manipulate it.

Comment: The simple solution as they in c++ books are written, are mostly OK. I suggest you to start from the simple, inheritance-based, template-free minimal example. Try this, and ask us again, what is the problem with _that_.

Comment: "works" seems a bit overstated here. You're overwriting unallocated memory, which will cause unspecified but probably disastrous problems at some later point in the program. (Try using valgrind for more details.)

Comment: Code has undefined behaviour, if it works for you it's because you were unlucky.

Comment: @john, when I first read your comment I thought it said "lucky" but your phrasing is best. It truly is unlucky if it causes you to think that it works properly when in fact it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here will fail horribly at some point because the size of the derived class is larger than the base class and you write after the end of the base class. The above write operation will overwrite memory that belongs to another object.
You can have a SetValue() method in the base class and implement it in the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not work. All you objects even after casting are still a `Base` because you constructed them as a base. The casts just say: Hey, I know it's a `Derived<xxx>`, so please just interpret that this way. You don't know this here, in fact you know it is NOT a `Derived`.

To properly use the objects, you need to create a `Derived<xxx>` and afterwards cast. If you use a `dynamic_cast` here all cases should come back as null as they are `Base`.

Given that you wanted to "pass a class through 5 functions" you'd probably want the inverted setup. Create `Derived<xxx>` objects and hold them as a pointer to `Base`. This works without casting as it should. Then pass the `Base*` through your functions. Polymorphism will take care that everything works fine.

Comment: I am not supposed to create derived class. So I'm thinking of adding a container of elements to base class.

Comment: You are defining `Derived` classes, but are not supposed to use them? That doesn't make any sense to me. You'll have to state more clearly what actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: I meant, the first object that gets passed to the functions is usually the base class. So, i got rid of the derived class and trying to find a way to add a multi-type array to the base class that one can assign any time.

Comment: You can still use the derived ones and pass those as a `Base*` given you find common functionality to derive. If there is no common functionality, e.g. a `print()` function, then they should probably not be handled by the same function.